# Buscador por nombre completo en sql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

[image: Buscador de nombres]

Buenas tengo este buscador la tabla esta en mysql y se llama socio, los campos son nombre y apellido,la consulta la hago mediante código php, estoy tratando de que cuando coloquen juan jaramillo, me traiga el listado de los Juan Pedro Jaramillo Perez
Pedro Juan Martinez Jaramillo.
trate de hacer esta consulta `select * from socio where nombre like '%juan%' or apellido like '%apellido%'`
pero le hice un echo a la consulta y me aparece es `select * from socio where nombre like '%juan jaramillo%' or apellido like '%juan jaramillo%'`
entonces no me trae ningun dato como puedo resolver esta duda muchas gracias si alguien sabe.

Comment: Pues, para buscar nombres, es complejo, te sugiero que vayas por palabras individuales en lugar de colocar el nombre completo, por ejemplo, en el caso de `Juan Pedro Jaramillo Perez`, si buscas como `%Juan Jaramillo%` NO te va a salir porque no cumple la condición, para que te salga, en la BD debería estar como `Pedro Juan Jaramillo Perez`, el orden importa. Lectura sugerida: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-like/

Answer (score 1):

Te esta faltando el `WHERE`

```
SELECT *
FROM socio
WHERE nombre LIKE '%nombre%' OR
apellido LIKE '%apellido%';
```

Comment: no con el where tampoco funciona

Comment: Esta respuesta es la correcta a la pregunta original.

Comment: @SneiderMuñoz a tu consulta original le faltaba el where. Ahora, tenes otro problema distinto, y es que tu pantalla manda los datos completos de nombre y apellido, y ahora tenes que separarlos....

Answer (score 1):

Tu variable que llega a la request de la búsqueda llega al backend toda junta.
Podrías separarla por espacios en blanco. Luego, la recorres con un foreach y agregas tantos OR como espacios en blanco tenga tu string de entrada.

Ejemplo algo asi

```
   $variableEntrada = "Juan Carlos Palma";
   $listaVarEntrada = explode(' ', $variableEntrada) //[0] Juan,[1] Carlos ,[2] Palma
```

Luego un foreach con la query

```
$query = "select * from socio "; 
$primeraVuelta =1;
foreach ($listaVarEntrada as $palabraBusqueda) {
   if($primeraVuelta===1)
 {
    $query = $query."WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$palabraBusqueda."%' OR apellido LIKE '%".$palabraBusqueda."%' ";// recuerda agregarle espacio al final para que no te quede pegada la query
    $primeraVuelta = 0;//para que entre solo una vez y coloque where
 }
 else{
    $query = $query."OR nombre LIKE '%".$palabraBusqueda."%' OR apellido LIKE '%".$palabraBusqueda."%' "; // recuerda agregarle espacio al final para que no te quede pegada la query
 }
}
$query = $query.";"; // al final agregas el ;
```

Espero te sirva compadre, saludos!